# SQL Server : create two columns from one

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have general tables where user reading is written. In one table there is a column called `odometerReading` where the user writes vehicle reading. One vehicle can have several `odometerReading` entries.

I want to use this column and create two columns in my #temp table. Start K will be the last `odometerReading` (if there is a previous record this will be the reading), End K (this will be the current reading the user puts in). If the vehicle has no previous record the start and end will be same. If the vehicle has previous records the start and end will be different).

The original SQL statement is too long for me to put on here. Any help your guidance will be really appreciated.

```
SELECT 
    #FuelSummary.Code, #FuelSummary.[Driver Name],
    #FuelSummary.[Start K], #FuelSummary.[Start K] AS 'Last K' 
FROM 
    #FuelSummary
```

[image]

Comment: I'm not certain, but it sounds like you want to use a `LAG()` window function (perhaps with `ISNULL()` to default to the current value if no previous value exists).

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like below

```
SELECT     
#FuelSummary.Code, #FuelSummary.[Driver Name], 
ISNULL(LAG(#FuelSummary.[Start K]) OVER (ORDER BY #FuelSummary.Code),0) [Start K] , #FuelSummary.[Start K] AS 'Last K' 
FROM #FuelSummary
ORDER BY #FuelSummary.Code
```